# How to find an AMI in the new AWS console version?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to create an instance in the Launch Configuration menu, but it is impossible to find the needed AMI from the dropdown.

- I expected following menu:

[image]

- But currently AWS provides the following possibilities ()selection from the dropdown:

[image]

- I can't find the needed AMI from the list (Linux for example)
  The bottom line is that I can't even use the `search` dropdown. It does not find existing AMI's:

[image]

**It's confusing and I do not know how to use AWS now...**

Answer (score 3):

## Ubuntu AMIs

Ubuntu [maintains a page with the latest AMIs in each region](https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/locator/ec2/) for your convenience and reference.

## Rocky Linux

Rocky Linux also maintains a [handy page for finding AMIs in each region](https://rockylinux.org/cloud-images/).

## Amazon or other specific vendor AMIs

The AWS console can be rather limiting, but you can [find the latest AMI with the awscli tool](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/query-for-the-latest-amazon-linux-ami-ids-using-aws-systems-manager-parameter-store/).

Get a list of Amazon images:

```
aws ec2 describe-images --owners amazon --filters "Name=name,Values=amzn*" --query 'sort_by(Images, &CreationDate)[].Name'
```

Use AWS Systems Manager paramater store to find the latest one with the name you want:

```
aws ssm get-parameters --names /aws/service/ami-amazon-linux-latest/amzn2-ami-hvm-x86_64-gp2 --region us-east-1
```

Then make sure you always use the latest when launching an instance:

```
aws ec2 run-instances --image-id $(aws ssm get-parameters --names /aws/service/ami-amazon-linux-latest/amzn2-ami-hvm-x86_64-gp2 --query 'Parameters[0].[Value]' --output text) --count 1 --instance-type m4.large
```

Comment: Also to note that images older than 2 years may now be hidden https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/03/amazon-machine-images-public-visibility-two-years/